# Sql statement into an array causing duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my first time using the site. I  need some help. When I run this code and get the output I get duplicated lines of data. So for instance a member maybe on the list 3 - 4 times depending on how many years he has gone to the events. I need to somehow combine any similar data into one row, if that makes sense? So John Doe should not be on the list 7 times just once with all the years he has gone.

```
$query_mem = "SELECT m.id, m.prefix, m.first_name, m.middle_name, m.last_name, m.suffix, m.member_class, m.jurisdiction_associated,
event.year,
m_event.attend 
FROM members AS m, event AS event, members_event AS m_event $where
AND m.member_class IN (1,3)
AND m.id = m_event.codigo_usuario AND m_event.type_event = event.codigo_inscricao
ORDER BY event.year, m.jurisdiction_associated, m.last_name, m.first_name";
$retorno_mem = $conexao->query($query_mem);
if(($conexao->errorCode() == '0') && ($retorno_mem->rowCount() > 0))
{
    while($registros_mem = $retorno_mem->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $prefix=$fname=$mname=$lname=$suffix=$address_1=$address_2=$city=$state=$zip=$country=$org=$campaign=NULL;

        $member_id          = ($registros_mem["id"]);
        $prefix             = ($registros_mem["prefix"]);
        $fname              = ($registros_mem["first_name"]);
        $mname              = ($registros_mem["middle_name"]);
        $lname              = ($registros_mem["last_name"]);
        $suffix             = ($registros_mem["suffix"]);
        $class              = getMemberClassName($conexao,$registros_mem["member_class"]);
        $jurisdiction   = getJurisdictionName($conexao,$registros_mem["jurisdiction_associated"]."000");
        $year                   = ($registros_mem["year"]);
        $attendance         = getMemberAttendanceName($conexao,$registros_mem["attend"]);


        $data1[] = array(
        ''.utf8_encode((int)$member_id).'',
        ''.utf8_encode($prefix).'',
        ''.utf8_encode($fname).'',
        ''.utf8_encode($mname).'',
        ''.utf8_encode($lname).'',
        ''.utf8_encode($suffix).'',
        ''.utf8_encode($class).'',
        ''.utf8_encode($jurisdiction).'',
        ''.utf8_encode($year).'',
        ''.utf8_encode($attendance).'',
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: Search the web for "SQL JOIN", "PDO prepared statements", "PDO parameter binding". When you learned how to use that all you can search for "GROUP BY" and "GROUP_CONCAT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the member's ID as the array key to see if he's already been, and if so just add to the `year` field. Something like this:

```
while($registros_mem = $retorno_mem->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $registros_mem['id'], $data1)
    {
        // We need to make year an array so it can hold multiple years.
        $registros_mem['year'] = [$registros_mem['year']];
        $data1[$registros_mem['id']] = $registros_mem;
    } else {
        $data1[$registros_mem['id']]['year'][] = $registros_mem['year'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am fairly new to Php and Sql so I need to add this while loop after the current code I have? So after I initialize the data1 array? Then what else do you think I would need to do? Thank you so much for your help I have been stressing over this for a week now.

Comment: @PandaCoffee That would replace your current while loop. There's no need to do all the copying stuff into vars, then into an array. The data comes back in an array, just use that. If you add `var_dump($data1)` after the while loop you'll be able to see the structure. You can even do `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($data1); echo '</pre>';` to see it in a more structured way.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error now. So I am not sure if it will work. It appears to have to do with the $registros_mem['year'] line I am trying to figure out where the error could be

Comment: yea it is this lines brackets $registros_mem['year'] = [$registros_mem['year']]; any ideas? I know you said this is where we were initializing a new array

Comment: If you're using an older version of PHP then it could be the square bracket shorthand. Try `$registros_mem['year'] = array($registros_mem['year']);`

Comment: Dam it didnt really work, I mean it did but I think it has to do with the way I have to output it all. I have to output it into an excel report. Thank you for trying to help though! I need to figure out another way I think.